# Create a new group by taking unique characters before a colon, and create aggregations on the output using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I wish to group by unique characters before the first colon and sum

**Data**

```
Box                 FALSE    TRUE
DDD8:0Y:1C611:100   1        2
DDD8:0Y:1C711:107   2        1
DDD8:0Y:1C711:109   3        5
AAS0:1T:1F500A:001  1        4
AAS0:1T:1F500A:002  2        2
AAS0:1T:1F500A:005  0        3
AAS0:1T:1F500A:005  2        3
```

**Desired**

```
    Box     FALSE   TRUE
    DDD8    6       8
    AA20    5       12
```

**Doing**

I am using str.split(':') in conjunction with groupby

```
df['Box'] = df['Box'].str.split(':').str[0]
groupby('key').sum()
```

However the final output labeling is not being produced. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Just a typo? `df.groupby("Box").sum()` worked fine for me. You're missing a `df` and referencing a non-existent `key` column.

Comment: Another option: `df.groupby(df['Box'].str.extract(r'^([^:]+)', expand=False))[['FALSE', 'TRUE']].sum().reset_index()`

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
out = df.pivot_table(index=df['Box'].str.split(':').str[0],
                     values=['FALSE', 'TRUE'], aggfunc='sum', 
                     sort=False).reset_index()
print(out)

# Output
    Box  FALSE  TRUE
0  DDD8      6     8
1  AAS0      5    12
```

**About your code:**

```
df['Box'] = df['Box'].str.split(':').str[0]
groupby('key').sum()
```

> However the final output labeling is not being produced. Any suggestion is appreciated.

I don't know about R but in Pandas 'key' should be an existing name of your `DataFrame`. `groupby` is a method (dot notation) of `DataFrame` and not a function. So your code raises a `NameError: name 'groupby' is not defined`  exception.

If you want to use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), you can do:

```
out = (df.assign(Box=df['Box'].str.split(':').str[0])
         .groupby('Box', as_index=False, sort=False)
         .sum(numeric_only=True))
print(out)

# Output
    Box  FALSE  TRUE
0  DDD8      6     8
1  AAS0      5    12
```